# How to convert hebrew (unicode) to Ascii in c#?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I have to create some sort of text file in which there are numbers and Hebrew letters decoded to ASCII.

This is file creation method which triggers on ButtonClick

```
protected void ToFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filename = Transactions.generateDateYMDHMS();
    string path = string.Format("{0}{1}.001", Server.MapPath("~/transactions/"), filename);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.ASCII);
    sw.WriteLine("hello");
    sw.WriteLine(Transactions.convertUTF8ASCII("שלום"));
    sw.WriteLine("bye");
    sw.Close();
}
```

as you can see, i use Transactions.convertUTF8ASCII() static method to convert from probably Unicode string from .NET to ASCII representation of it. I use it on term Hebrew 'shalom' and get back '????' instead of result i need.

Here is the method.

```
public static string convertUTF8ASCII(string initialString)
{
    byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(initialString);
    byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, unicodeBytes);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiBytes);
}
```

Instead of having initial word decoded to ASCII i get '????' in the file i create even if i run debbuger i get same result.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi ,So how have you solved it? I have the same problem.Need to convert Hebrew unicode (1400 ,1500 etc ) to ASCII codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply translate arbitrary unicode characters to ASCII. The best it can do is discard the unsupportable characters, hence `????`. Obviously the basic 7-bit characters will work, but not much else. I'm curious as to what the expected result is?

If you need this for *transfer* (rather than representation) you might consider base-64 encoding of the underlying UTF8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I have 'Œ€‹‰' this kind of characters in example file, though it does not represent 'shalom' but you will get an idea what kind of Encoding it is. I could not understand what do you mean by 'transfer' to base-64.

Comment: @eugeneK - it still isn't obvious to me what the translation is there. I suspect I'd need to see the exact byte sequence and character code-points that are supposed to map to each other for it to "click".

Comment: i've got requirement with mistake which lead me to ASCII at first place. Thanks for the info anyways.

Comment: eugeneK Please post how did you handle that?

Answer (score 2):

Do you perhaps mean ANSI, not ASCII?

ASCII doesn't define any Hebrew characters. There are however some ANSI code pages which do such as "windows-1255"

In which case, you may want to consider looking at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

In short, where you have:

```
Encoding.ASCII
```

You would replace it with:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)
```

Comment: you probably right. i have no experience with Encoding at all hence i never knew ASCII doesn't contain hebrew chars

Comment: @eugueK ASCII is pretty much just the English alphabet, 0-9, basic punctuation and some control characters. Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: nopes, i've got requirement with mistake which lead me to ASCII at first place. Thanks for the info anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps asking about [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) (as in "[Romanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew)") instead of encoding conversion, if you really are talking about ASCII?

Comment: nopes, i've got requirement with mistake which lead me to ASCII at first place. Thanks for the info anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue when original xml file was in ASCII Encoding.

As Userx suggested

> Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)

```
XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(xmlPath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)));
```

So now my XDocument file can read hebrew even if the xml file was saved as ASCII