# Convert Hebrew chars to English

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

To prevent marking my question as "duplicate" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649904/how-to-convert-hebrew-unicode-to-ascii-in-c)  is the "answer" to the similar question , which unfortunately doesn't work.So I have the situation where I type Hebrew text into TextBox and I need to convert each typed letter into standard char codes like those in ASCII table (decimal) for English language.Because converting Hebrew chars directly returns entirely different code( those seem to be Unicode ) I need to convert Hebrew input into English. I tried different Encoder types for Hebrew input conversion :Unicode , UTF8 , UTF16 , "Windows-1255" .I am always  getting "?" .

So for example ,possible solution from the question mentioned above is this:

```
  public static string convertUTF8ASCII(string initialString)
  {
     byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(initialString);
     byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, unicodeBytes);
     return Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255").GetString(asciiBytes);
  }
```

And it doesn't work.

I have also tried something like this :

```
  public static int GetASCIICodeFromUnicode(string letter){
     Encoding ascii = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
     Encoding unicode = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");

     byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(letter);

     byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);
    
     char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
     ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
     asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
     string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);

     return (int)Convert.ToChar(asciiString);
 }
```

Doesn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps I am being simple here, but how exactly is that supposed to work? Hebrew has 26 characters in its alphabet, English 22.

Comment: It should work the same way as it is mapped on the English -Hebrew keyboard ,I think.

Comment: By the time you have entered Hebrew, .NET already has the _unicode_ values, not any ASCII or such. You can't get bytes from that, convert and assume it will convert.

Comment: Are you trying to say my only way out is to map the codes manually in some long switch statement?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you that when a user tries to enter English when on a Hebrew keyboard you want to recover the original attempted English?

Comment: No , I need to get ASCII key values from Hebrew input and not Unicode.Like if "ג" was pressed which is "D" in English layout ,I need to get code =68 and not something like 1400 + .

Comment: Then a switch statement (or `Dictionary<char,char>`) would probably be the most efficient and easy solution.

Comment: Then you are going to need to map each Hebrew letter to then English letter in that position on the keyboard.  How could you expect that Encoding.Convert would map positions on the keyboard?

Comment: Yeah , that is what I see I finally  have to do.Thanks @Oded .

Comment: I'll write that up as an answer.

Comment: @Blam I would do numeric conversion afterwards.

Comment: I would still like to ask what you want to accomplish with that. Now you have a string of some ASCII letters. What is this string good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you get strings appearing in .NET, it is too late to find out what the keyboard sent out.

In order to find out what *keyboard* position was clicked you will need to have a mapping of the Hebrew to English positions - a `Dictionary<char,char>` is a good candidate data structure for this.